# Android monkey crashing on holoeverywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere, monkey

I'd like to test my app with the monkey testing tool, but it only gets up until 700 events, than it crashes with some vague log message:

```
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165444, class org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class org.holoeverywhere.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:3213)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:712)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRootImpl.java:3074)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchMode(ViewRootImpl.java:3058)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3202)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4344)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-18 13:56:44.600: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is how I start the monkey tool:

```
adb shell monkey -p app.package -v 300000
```

Any ideas how to get past this error?

Comment: if you can show us your code where you set your adapter would be good to know where you are doing mistake.

Comment: in onCreateView(I use 1 FragmentActivity, and lots of fragments) I set up the adapter, add a footerview to the listview, than set the adapter to the listview, than start an asynctask to load the items, and in onProgressUpdate I add the items to the adapter.

Comment: also, this seems to happen with listviews, that have views in the listview items, that are clickable (eg: they have 2 columns of items, also: listView.setItemsCanFocus(true))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appranetly, I had some AsyncTasks that could have been running after a fragment died, and threw these vague logs.
The only helpful part of the log was "...ListView(2131165444...", so I checked gen/package/R.java to see what that layout id is, and it turned out to be a listview, that had the faulty asynctask working on the list items.